# Code Coverage Coloring in VS 2012 not working

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

As the title says, the coloring is not working. If I to go tools > options and look for 'Coverage Touched'  etc in the list of Fonts and Colors, they don't exist there.

If I run the tests with the option to analyse them for coverage, no colors show up in the editor. I have VS 2012 Premium update 3 installed.

I already:

- resetted usersettings
- ran in safemode (can't run tests then, so useless)
- re-installed VS
- rebooted everything

A colleague of mine used the exact same installer/image, and it works for him...

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resetted Userdata (for the 10th time) and I noticed that by default it migrates the settings from 2010 or something. I now unmarked that checkbox, and the problem is now solved.

I'm not 100% sure if the checkbox was the problem, but thats the only difference I can recall.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. What check box are you referring to?

Comment: the checkbox, migrate settings from 2010